# How to change navigationBar color for only for UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to change the `UIImagePickerController's` navigation bar color in `SwiftUI`. But it's not working. I tried many ways by changing the appearance and `backgroundcolor` of navigation bar and so on..

But, nothing worked. I was also tried by changing navigation appearances in `AppDelegate` but doesn’t worked.

**It's changing back to light gray after showing image picker.**

```swift
typealias ImageBlock =  ((_ image: UIImage?, _ name: String?) -> Void)

struct ImagePickerRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    private
    var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .photoLibrary
    
    private
    var imageBlock: ImageBlock?
    
    init(sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .photoLibrary,
         _ imageBlock: @escaping ImageBlock) {
        self.sourceType = sourceType
        self.imageBlock = imageBlock
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePickerRepresentable>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = sourceType
        imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
        // tried here
//        imagePicker.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .red
        return imagePicker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePickerRepresentable>) {
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self, imageBlock: imageBlock)
    }
    
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        private var imageBlock: ImageBlock?
        
        var parent: ImagePickerRepresentable
        
        init(_ parent: ImagePickerRepresentable, imageBlock: ImageBlock?) {
            self.parent = parent
            self.imageBlock = imageBlock
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
            if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                var fileName = ""
                if let asset = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.phAsset] as? PHAsset {
                    if let name = asset.value(forKey: "filename") as? String{
                        fileName = name
                        self.imageBlock?(image, fileName)
                    }
                } else {
                    imageBlock?(image, "IMG_")
                }
            }
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
        // tried here
        func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
//            if navigationController is UIImagePickerController {
//                let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
//                appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
//                appearance.backgroundColor = .red
//                viewController.navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance;
//                viewController.navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = viewController.navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance
//            }
        }
    }
}
```

// Content View

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showPicker = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button {
                    showPicker.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Select Image")
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showPicker) {
                ImagePickerRepresentable(sourceType: .photoLibrary) { image, name in

                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot [image: Navigation bar]

Comment: You know that UIImagePickerController is deprecated, right?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller but not complete complete component right? only some of the variables am I right?